# Присоединительный или соединительный союз?

Tags: запятые, союзы

Знаешь… — как-то горько начал он и остановился.

Интонационно сюда просилась запятая, полезла искать обоснование — и засомневалась, подходит ли этот случай под правило присоединительной конструкции. Помогите, пожалуйста, определиться.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***— Знаешь… — как-то горько начал он и остановился.***

Здесь при оформлении прямой речи используется **многоточие**, обозначающее незаконченность высказывания, поэтому считать союз И присоединительным и обозначать паузу перед ним нет необходимости.

Вообще говоря, это возможно, но делается нечасто и  в предложениях с подходящей для этого структурой (см. пример у Розенталя).

В предложениях с однородными сказуемыми это скорее авторский знак и авторская пауза.

Розенталь: [Присоединительный или соединительный союз?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450238/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7)

2. Если союз И имеет **присоединительное** значение (с помощью этого союза может присоединяться также неоднородный член предложения), то перед ним ставится запятая: [Лизавета Ивановна] **разливала чай, и получала выговоры** за лишний расход сахара;

Comment: Авторское решение. Мне кажется, что это лишнее. Но если обозначать, то лучше тире, а не запятой. В то же время смотрятся оба знака (тире или запятая) не лучшим образом.